# How to install openmpi from Macports on Sierra and/or check if openmpi is already installed

Tags: macports, openmpi

I am trying to install openmpi from Macports on Sierra 10.12.5. It seems that it is a straight forward command:

```
sudo port install openmpi
```

When I do this, I get the error:

```
sudo: port: command not found
```

I gathered from similar threads that this may be due to openmpi already being installed. How can I check if it is installed, and if so, uninstall it so that I can reinstall it using Macports with the above command? Any thoughts would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By default, the port command is installed at /opt/local/bin/port.  The installer normally modifies your PATH environment variable to include '/opt/local/bin' so that you can launch stuff installed by MacPorts just by entering the name of the command.  I think you should re-do the MacPorts installation.  Follow:

https://www.macports.org/install.php

You almost certainly want to use the macOS package installer.  You may have to restart Terminal for the new PATH to take effect.